CAPL Script in CAnoe Report generation takes too long
I have written a CAPL script for a testcase which will execute for 65535 times (0xFFFF), i have used for loop to do that. the execution is working fine , but it takes around 14-15 hours of time to generate the report, what is the problem here?
the testcase name and title is provided by xml file.
I have written the CAPL testcase to perform some simple comparison with the values from 0 - 0xFFFF and return teststeppass, if the condition is met else teststepfail will happen, this testcase is executed for 65535 times, since the for loop is used to achieve the condition. The report generation is taking too long to generate.

This is something to be reported to Vector's support.
